# Rails error undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Having a bit of a rough time on this example, my code reads as:

view

```
<%  monthNumber = (Time.now - 1.month).strftime("%m") # 
yearNumber = (Time.now).strftime("%Y") # 
monthWord = (Time.now - 1.month).strftime("%B")# 
monthYear = "#{monthNumber}-#{yearNumber}"
createdAtCount = 0 
creationDateCount = 0 %>

<h1>Stats for <%= monthWord %></h1>

<p><%= monthNumber  %>-<%= yearNumber %></p>

<% @votsphonebooks.each do |entry| %>
    <% if entry.CreationDate.include? monthYear %>
        <p>test</p>
    <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def reports
   @votsphonebooks = Votsphonebook.order("id DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5000)
end
```

I can, for example in the loop, run through all the first names, so the loop is working OK, but as soon as I try to test if the 'CreationDate' includes '10-2016' (which also works fine), it gets the error.

CreationDate column has the format: 11-10-2016 - 10:51 AM

Thanks!

Comment: The `CreationDate` value for that particular `votsphonebook` is `nil`, so is the error. And the **column names** should be in **camel case** FWI.

Comment: Please refer this doc http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F